# GEB : Find Element By CSS locator

Tags: css, geb

In GEB script, I'm trying to find an element by CSS locator. But,

The following css locator, worked from 'FireFinder'. But, the same is not working in script.

```
"table[class^='combo']>tbody>tr>td[id^='combo-']>input[type='text']"
```

In the script I'm accessing with the below statement:

```
inputSchdule {module TextField, $("table[class^='combo']>tbody>tr>td[id^='combo-']>input[type='text']")}
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Although, you might need spaces between >  selectors. Remember that geb selection is not true css. So its not a true css interpreter. $("table[class^='combo'] > tbody > tr > td[id^='combo-'] > input[type='text']")